# What does this expression "C<>M<>Y" mean?

Tags: math, colors, logic, expression, printers

With respect to this question, CMY stands for the Colors: Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow.

I recently came across a statement that says,

> If CMY are 0 the image is black and white, if C=M=Y and not 0, the image is Grayscale, if C<>M<>Y the image is color.

I understand the other two but not sure what "C<>M<>Y" means.
Can someone please explain its meaning with two or more examples?

Comment: the `<>` means not equal ... in C/C++ languages is operator `!=` used instead

Answer (score 2):

C is less than or greater than M and M is less than or greater than Y.

Comment: or Can I just say C, M, Y have unique values?

Comment: @Shubham - that would be another way of saying what that pseudo-code said. However, the pseudo-code is (slightly) wrong. Specifically, two of the three color channels can be the same, and it will still be a color, not gray. That is `3 <> 3 <> 4` is `false`, because `3 <> 3` is `false` - but that is wrong; that is not gray, therefore it has a color. The correct formula is simply the negative of the gray scale one:  `not (C equals M equals Y)`. But this is nit-picking.

Answer (score 1):

*the other comment says basically the same thing, realized it just before posting*

In excel and some languages `<>` is `not equal` so:

```
if(Cyan <> Magenta){
   print('Image isn't grayscale')
}
```

Comment: Okay so, JavaScripts Devs Like me: Can Consider it as this expression `C != M && M!= Y`, Right?

Comment: yep, sorry for answering after a while, also not sure about the  `AND` or `&&`